# Failing Two Test Cases, Missing Integer Codility Problem

Tags: java

The Question:
Write a function, that, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.

For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.

Given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4.

Given A = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000].

What I'm not understanding is how I'm failing these two cases, while also having 100% correctness

Also I'm not sure what cases I'm not covering, I managed for the case of 1 not existing in the first if statement, if there is a missing element in my for each loop, and finally, in the case of no missing element, to return the largest int + 1

Any help in clearing the confusion (and improvements for my time complexity) would be greatly appreciated

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        //int counter = 0;
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Arrays.sort(A);
        for(int n : A){
            if(n > 0){
               // counter++;
                set.add(n);
            }
        }
        //returns if set does not contain 1
        if(!set.contains(1)){
            return 1;
        }
        //returns missing int if it does not exist in set
        for(int n: set){
           if(!set.contains(n+1)){
                return n+1;
            }
        }
        //if no missing ints, returns end of array + 1
        return A[A.length-1];
    }
}
```

Answer Results:

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is.  When I run your code with `[1, 2, 3]`, I get `4` and with ` [−1, −3]` I get `1`.  Why don't you include a complete runnable example so that we can reproduce exactly what you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you over-killed. first, using a hashset can lead to O(N) algorithm, which you have to avoid sort (O(NlogN)). But due to large memory footprint, I'd rather go with a sort and it is practically faster. Second, if you choose a sort of A, then a simple for-loop with detect any gap in the positive part of the array, which is now your result. You should avoid Hashset and the many loops in your code

Answer (score -1):

I would use a [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

Advantage: Fast scan for missing value. Performance: *O(n)*

```java
public static int solution(int... values) {
    BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
    for (int v : values)
        if (v > 0)
            bitSet.set(v);
    return bitSet.nextClearBit(1);
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(solution(1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2));
System.out.println(solution(1, 2, 3));
System.out.println(solution(-1, -3));
```

*Output*

```
5
4
1
```